# Some polygons failing to fill with color

Tags: r, polygon, sp, rgeos

I have several Spatial Polygon Data Frames I am adding successively to a plot in R 4.0.2. The polygons represent US States, National Forests, National Parks, and wildfire perimeters. While it probably doesn't make sense to provide links to all the data for a fully reproduced working example, the following code is a simplified version of the plot I made:

```
# equal area projection
proj_coords <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

# load libraries
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

# Make a bbox of the total extent
e <- as(raster::extent(-1400000,-850000,2300000,2750000), "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(e) <- proj_coords

# Make a smaller box to add to the plot for Stack overflow example
e2 <- as(raster::extent(-1300000,-900000,2400000,2650000), "SpatialPolygons")
proj4string(e2) <- proj_coords

# Plot
lt.green <- adjustcolor("lightgreen", alpha.f = 0.5)
plot(e,axes=T,xlim=c(-1150000,-1100000),ylim=c(2350000,2700000),lwd=2,border="grey",xlab="m",ylab="m")
plot(e2,add=T,col=lt.green,border="grey")
```

My question:

In my real plot, `e2` are National Forest boundaries, some of which extend beyond the extent of the plot axes. When I try to add them to the plot with

```
lt.green <- adjustcolor("lightgreen", alpha.f = 0.5) 
plot(e2,add=T,col=lt.green,border="grey")
```

all of the National Forest boundaries plot, but some of them are not filled with color. This is true both when I print the graphic in the console and when I try to export it as a png.

Below is the actual png. The polygons with empty, thin gray borders are the National Forests that are failing to fill with color, while the green ones are correctly filled.

[image]

Comment: GIS SE site has policy of focused questions, so please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Should I delete it and repost it?

Comment: No, just edit it and focus on one question only.